# Make an ul move up while adding every li

Tags: jquery, css, html

I got an an array from server, I need to add them in an ul and make the ul move up.

Just like your message coming or sending. But if there's one or two li, they would be at the bottom of the ul instead being top.

First nothing in the ul. append a li, and ul move up the height of this new li. Then append the next life and continue like that

How am I gonna do this using css and jQuery?

In my mind.   .html

```
<div>
  <ul class="container">
  </ul>
</div>
```

I don't know how to assemble those css and jQuery to make it move up.

I'd be appreciated for your answer or comments.

Comment: Could you show something you have tried to achieve the same?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2x1wnxe7/

Comment: @JonasGrumann I think OP also wants to add  `$(".chatcontainer").scrollTop($(".chatcontainer").get(0).scrollHeight);` to your click event so that it scrolls to the bottom of the list automatically. Kinda like a shoutbox/twitterbox

Comment: @JonasGrumann yours looks like append a li at the top. I want to append a li to ul bottom and move up a certain height at every time appending

Comment: I voted to reopen.  Though the question is not worded near as well as it could be, I don't think it's that difficult to understand what the OP wants.  If you look at my answer, I don't think it's too difficult to figure out what the OP is asking.  They want to add some `<li>` tags to a `<ul>` and then scroll it up so that the most recent content that was just added are displayed, no matter how many have been added.  This would be very similar to how any sort of live feed works where it adds content to the end of a list and scrolls the list to make sure the newest content is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a series of `<li>` tags from an array of data like this:

```
var data = [
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four",
    "Five",
    "Six",
    "Seven",
    "Eight",
    "Nine",
    "Ten"
];

var container = $(".container");
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    container.append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});

// calculate new scroll position and then animate to it
var pos = container.height() - $(".scrollContainer").height();
pos = Math.max(pos, 0);
$(".scrollContainer").animate({scrollTop: pos}, 500);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xo03pu79/

Or a different version that adds one at a time and keeps even the first items scroll to the bottom is here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h90x13L2/

And, a version that runs off a timer: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bonw1mft/

---

Scrolling it up requires putting it in a containing div that is set to scroll, calculating the new height after you've added the content and setting the scroll position of the container so that the bottom of the content is aligned with the bottom of the containing div.

Comment: Please complete the code. append a li, move up. After a interval time, add the next li and move up

Comment: @ronan - if you look at the jsFiddle, it adds items upon each button click.  I think you should be able to adapt that to your specific logic (if you want a timer, you can add that).  If you have a more specific question about how to do that, then please ask a more specific question about how to do something.  We are here to answer specific questions, not write finished code for you.

Comment: thanks. The first time didn't notice the add button, I just saw the effect wasn't that correct, I should be more concentrate on the code. And I think this comment taught a lot. Appreciate it.

Comment: @ronan - why'd you remove the accepted answer checkmark?  Did this concept not work for you?

Comment: I rethink it. If I minus the data array to one, adding a li, it would appear at the top. You achieved ul move up when there are many li. Not every li is at the bottom of ul. Can you help me out?

Comment: @ronan - see this version: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/h90x13L2/

Comment: I tried to remove Mathmama line, nothing changed. Please amend your fiddle

Comment: @ronan - please see my latest comment with new fiddle.

Comment: I've seen this one. You add margin-top, it's a little bit tricky. Haha , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds easy enough.  You just need to use jquery selectors to slice and dice to get the li into the correct position.

Take a look at [nth-child() selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: Could you put jsfiddle here according to what I post and what you understand